# PSFTP How to get file name from Dir command using RegExp

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, directory, psftp

I'm trying to use a regular expression to parse a log file generated from a `dir` command from PSFTP.

Example Dir example 1

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 0        0                  0 Jun 21 13:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 0        0                  0 Jun 21 13:13 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 0        0                897 Jun 20 15:02 EQA.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 0        0                897 Jun 20 15:06 EQA1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 0        0                897 Jun 16 20:41 Test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 0        0                897 Jun 16 21:46 Test1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 0        0                897 Jun 21 13:13 Test4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 0        0                913 May 31 18:01 test.123456789.txt
psftp> bye
```

Example Dir example 2

```
drwx------    2 MikePC-apps users        4096 Apr  5  2016 .
drwx------    4 MikePC-apps users        4096 Jan 20  2016 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 MikePC-apps users          82 Apr  5  2016 test.txt.$01
-rw-r--r--    1 MikePC-apps users          82 Aug 10  2016 test.txt.$02
-rw-r--r--    1 MikePC-apps users          82 Aug 10  2016 test.txt.asc
-rw-r--r--    1 MikePC-apps users          82 Aug 10  2016 test1.txt.$01
-rw-r--r--    1 MikePC-apps users        1927 Apr  4  2016 test.zip
```

So from what I found around the net, if a file is older than 6 months or in the future, the year is displayed instead of time in the day.

For example 1, I'm using a regex `:/d/d/s .*.*.*` followed by substring function to retrieve file names.

But I don't know how to approach the second example. I was hoping maybe there's a parameter for `dir` command to include the time stamp so I can use the same regex. Or maybe there is another regular expression that can handle both examples.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            string[] inputs = {
                                  "drwxr-xr-x 1 0        0                  0 Jun 21 13:13 .",
                                  "ddrwxr-xr-x 1 0        0                  0 Jun 21 13:13 ..",
                                  "d-rw-r--r-- 1 0        0                897 Jun 20 15:02 EQA.txt",
                                  "d-rw-r--r-- 1 0        0                897 Jun 20 15:06 EQA1.txt",
                                  "d-rw-r--r-- 1 0        0                897 Jun 16 20:41 Test.txt",
                                  "d-rw-r--r-- 1 0        0                897 Jun 16 21:46 Test1.txt",
                                  "d-rw-r--r-- 1 0        0                897 Jun 21 13:13 Test4.txt",
                                  "d-rw-r--r-- 1 0        0                913 May 31 18:01 test.123456789.txt",
                                  "drwx------    2 MikePC-apps users        4096 Apr  5  2016 .",
                                  "drwx------    4 MikePC-apps users        4096 Jan 20  2016 ..",
                                  "-rw-r--r--    1 MikePC-apps users          82 Apr  5  2016 test.txt.$01",
                                  "-rw-r--r--    1 MikePC-apps users          82 Aug 10  2016 test.txt.$02",
                                  "-rw-r--r--    1 MikePC-apps users          82 Aug 10  2016 test.txt.asc",
                                  "-rw-r--r--    1 MikePC-apps users          82 Aug 10  2016 test1.txt.$01",
                                  "-rw-r--r--    1 MikePC-apps users        1927 Apr  4  2016 test.zip"
                              };

            string pattern = @"^(?'attrib'[^\s]+)\s+(?'links'[^\s]+)\s+(?'owner'[^\s]+)\s+(?'group'[^\s]+)\s+(?'size'[^\s]+)\s+(?'date'.+)\s+(?'filename'[^$]+)$";

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
                Console.WriteLine("attrib : '{0}', links : '{1}', owner : '{2}', group : '{3}', size : '{4}', date : '{5}', filename : '{6}'",
                    match.Groups["attrib"].Value, match.Groups["links"].Value, match.Groups["owner"].Value, match.Groups["group"].Value,
                    match.Groups["size"].Value, match.Groups["date"].Value, match.Groups["filename"].Value); 
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution,
I modify the Pattern to `string pattern = @"^(?'attrib'[^\s]+)\s+(?'links'[^\s]+)\s+(?'owner'[^\s]+)\s+(?'group'[^\s]+)\s+(?'size'[^\s]+)\s+(?'date'.+)\s+(?'filename'.+)$";`

this is also included `test1.txt.$01` as filename. +1 (sorry cant up vote)

Thanks

Comment: The $01 is part of the filename

Comment: I tested the regex `([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(.+)\s+([^$]+)` on [Regexr](http://regexr.com/) and it stopped at $ due to [^] is a negated set.
I removed $ at the end of the pattern because the string is already split into sentence